# Не понятная ошибка:

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
def get_forenames_and_surenames():
    forenames = []
    surenames = []
    for names, filename in ((forenames, "data_forenames.txt"),
                            (surenames, "data_surnames.txt")):
        for name in open(filename, encoding="cp1251"):
            names.append(name.rstrip())
    return forenames, surenames

forenames, surenames = get_forenames_and_surenames()
fh = open("test-names1.txt", "w", encoding="cp1251")
for i in range(100):
    line = "{0} {1}\n".format(random.choice(forenames),
                              random.choice(surenames))
    fh.write(line)
fh.close()
```

Объясните пожалуйста смысл ошибки, и как исправить

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\programs\learning_program\generate_test_names\generate_test_names1.py", line 16, in <module>
    fh.write(line)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: У вас в файле, похоже, кодировка не совместимая с utf-8. Попробуйте cp1251

Comment: cp1251 это кодировка?

Comment: Ага, она же `windows-1251`. Вообще, я пальцем в небо тыкнул, лучше приложить в вопрос пример того файла. Кодировки это дело такое щекотливое :)

Comment: Здесь нет сноски "Прикрепить файл". Как это сделать?

Comment: Не помогло с cp1251? Кст, у вас на обоих файлах та ошибка? А давайте как текст попробуем -- нужна только первая строка. Добавьте ее в вопрос, выделите и нажмите в редакторе на кнопку `{}`. Или можете как base64 приложить файл :) Или откройте файл в бинарном режиме и считайте первую строку, после ее приложите к вопросу. Могу подробнее об любом из вариантов рассказать

Comment: C cp1251 вышло, теперь вылетела новая ошибка:

Comment: Добавьте ошибку в вопрос (кнопка `править`)